# Scan for iBeacon upon receiving remote notification

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ibeacon, azure-notificationhub

I currently have an app setup to receive remote notifications using Azure Notification Hub.
Now, I would like to scan for iBeacons, see if a specific one is close by and if so, the notification should not be shown to the user. However, if the beacon isn't in sight, the user should receive this notification.

Basically I want the beacon to supress the notifications for this app.

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the docs from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started), when a remote notification comes in, you get a callback like this:

```
public class MyHandler extends NotificationsHandler {
  public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
  private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
  Context ctx;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
    ctx = context;
    String nhMessage = bundle.getString("message");
    sendNotification(nhMessage);
    if (MainActivity.isVisible) {
        MainActivity.mainActivity.ToastNotify(nhMessage);
    }
  }

  private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    // put your notification code here
    ...
  }
```

}

If you want to filter the notifications based on what beacons are present, you can add that logic to the onReceive method like this:

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
     if (!(MyApplication)this.getApplication()).isBeaconVisible()) {
        // Suppress notification by returning early from method
        return;
     }
     ...
  }
```

The above `isBeaconVisible()` could be implemented in a custom Android Application class using the Android Beacon Library with something like below.  You'll need to read more about how to set up that library to make this work.  You'll also need to register the custom Application class in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {

    public Collection<Beacon> mVisibleBeacons;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        // TODO: look up the proper I_BEACON_LAYOUT in a google search
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(I_BEACON_LAYOUT));
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("all-beacons", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        mVisibleBeacons = beacons;
    }

    public boolean isBeaconVisible() {
        return mVisibleBeacons.size() > 0;
    }
}
```

The above logic for `isBeaconVisible()` returns true if any beacon with any identifier has been seen in the last second.   But you can alter this to make it more sophisticated per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some opensource library to work with beacons. I used Altbeacon library for example.
Here is the samples : https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html
For your target you need to implement BeaconConsumer interface on Activity or Service. It has a method onBeaconServiceConnect(). Example of implementation:

```
    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override 
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() == 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Show your notification here");        
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("someRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }
```